# spring security HTTP Status 403 - Access Denied

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, access-denied

Login is success but spring security blocking url even i given access to **USER** . How can i manage this thing?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("sahil").password("123")
                .roles("ADMIN","USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/welcome","/inventory/**","/sales/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();
    }
```

**LoginController.java**

```
    @Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/login" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLoginPage() {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleUserLogin(ModelMap model, @RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String password) {
        if (!service.validateUser(name, password)) {
            model.put("errorMsg", "Invalid Credential");
            return "login";
        }
        System.out.println("principal : " + getLoggedInUserName());
        model.put("name", name);
        model.put("password", password);
        return "welcome";
    }

    private String getLoggedInUserName() {

        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            System.out.println("in if");
          return  ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();

        } else {
            System.out.println("in else");
         return principal.toString();

        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showWelcomeDashboard() {
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

**1 .** Once Login success page redirected to welcome page but url is still **localhost:8080/login** instead of **localhost:8080/welcome**.

[image: welcome dashboard]

**2.** After redirecting to URL **localhost:8080/sales** is it 403 Access denied.

[image: sales page]

Comment: Hi, try to change this .access("hasRole('USER')") to this .access("ROLE_USER")

Comment: @Error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'ROLE_USER'

Comment: @PraveenKumarLalasangi : I already tried, few more clarification i added , can you please check now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What is spring security**
Spring security is all about authentication and authorization, in your case you are missing authentication. There is no configuration of authentication in your security configuration. What you are missing is authentication filter for your spring security. Spring security provides default authentication filter `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` that can be configured by `.formLogin()`. You can use default provided or you can define your own custom authentication filter(Implementation of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`).

Once authentication is success spring security will grant authorities for authenticated user. If authentication is configured correctly, below configuration is responsible for authentication and granting authority

```java
auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("sahil").password("123")
                .roles("ADMIN","USER");
```

Authenticated users each request will be passed through filter `FilterSecurityInterceptor` and it will verifies authority granted for authenticated user with authorization configured for resources as given in below code.

```java
.antMatchers("/welcome","/inventory/**","/sales/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
```

You missed all this by not configuring authentication filter.
Now for making it simple use.formLogin() in your http configuration.

```java
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/welcome","/inventory/**","/sales/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
    .and().exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedPage("/403")
    .and().formLogin()
    .and().logout()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout=true")
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
    .and()
        .csrf()
            .disable();
}
```

`.formLogin()` without any configuration provides default login page with username and password default form parameters.And after authentication it redirects to `"/"` If you want to provide your custom login page then use below configuration.

```java
.and().formLogin()
       .loginPage("/login")
       .usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password")
       .defaultSuccessUrl("/app/user/dashboard")
       .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
```

`.loginPage("")` - Your custom login page URL
`.usernameParameter("").passwordParameter("")` - Your custom login form parameters
`.defaultSuccessUrl("")` - Page url after successful authentication
`.failureUrl("")` - Page url after authentication failure

<sub>Note: You should not use "/login" POST method in your controller, Even though if you write, it will not be reached from spring security filter chain. As your configuration was wrong before, it was reaching before! Now you remove those from your controller and use conventional approach as mentioned above.</sub>

Comment: @PraveenKumarLalasangi Great explanation. Can you share resource from where you studied spring boot. i am pretty new for spring boot with just basic knowledge of spring core.

Comment: Thanks, Spring boot and conventional Spring-mvc has no difference except spring boot comes with default auto configuration, I have not studied spring from any tutorials but what i do is i will go for spring documentation and refer and implement what i need. While working in spring/spring security enabling debug logs and analyzing logs helped me understanding internal architecture. Still everyday is learning sometimes we may be wrong what we understood, so everytime cross checking concepts with practical implementation clears concepts and helps me to understand.

Comment: I write answer to analyse myself, expecting someone will point at my mistake and notifies me. Or someone will write alternative approach, which helps me learning that too.